# AngularJS the width doesn't corespond

Tags: javascript, angularjs, width, element, directive

I want to get an element width, but when I inspect the element, it have 71px, but when I debug the value is 69px.

```
app.directive('minijobsItemPrincipal', function ( ) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        controller: function ( $element, $window ) {
            this.getItemWidth = function ( ) {
                $element.css('background-color', 'red');
                console.log ( $element[0].offsetWidth )
            }
        }
    };
});
```

So, if I use `console.log ( $element )`, and I search in console the `clientWidth` value appears 71px, but if I use `console.log ( $element[0].clientWidth )`, it appears 69px, I can't understand why.

Comment: When I use console.log($element[0]) in console is printed the element with content http://i.imgur.com/1HbxraA.png

Comment: Yep same, clientWidth: 71 and if I use $element[0].clientWidth result is 69.

Comment: I don't know to configure on jsFiddle, just don't work on jsfiddle :(, maybe is from css style?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/L80ysdoy/) you can find a fiddle to your directive. But I can't see the issue you're having.

Comment: I tested on Firefox and working good, just on Chrome gave a bad value, I can give you the link of template tomorrow (because I host on Xampp)

Comment: http://109.99.67.215:80/minijobs you can test untill 11:30 PM